# Android PullToRefresh onScrollListener not working

Tags: android, listview, pull-to-refresh

I have [chrisbanes PullToRefresh lib](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh) working in my project. Now I need to intercept scroll events to add some logic, it seems that the library is prepared to set `onScrollListener`, and I tried to add one with

```
myList.setOnScrollListener(this);
```

and

```
myList.getRefreshableView().setOnScrollListener(this);
```

but the listener methods are never called. I guess this has something to do with `PullToRefreshBase` class overriding `onTouchEvent` and `onInterceptTouchEvent`, but can't figure out how can I fix the issue, or maybe I'm missing something simple.

Did anyone succeeded adding `onScrollListeners` to PullToRefresh List?

Answer (score 0):

For the change you will considered to listen the scroll bar .
To use the Scroll state change Listener  I hope it will use to get the solution for you...

```
 listStudies.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            if ((MainActivity.listsize - MainActivity.currentlistitemposition) <= 3
                    && listagain == 0) {
                listagain = 1;
                System.out.println(MainActivity.listsize);
                System.out.println(MainActivity.currentlistitemposition);
                currentPage++;
                try {
                    performRequest(currentPage);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    // "Error occuered during the Request...",
                    // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        }
    });
```

Because Am also using  chrisbanes PullToRefresh lib So i hope it will usefull for you..Best of Luck...